# codeigniter - compare values

Tags: codeigniter, compare

I need to compare two values in a table: cliente and nro_cuota, if both exist I don't want to add it.

Here is my code

```
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_theme('datatables');

    $crud->set_table('cobranzas');

    $crud->set_subject('Cobranzas');

    $crud->set_language('spanish');

    $crud->required_fields(
        'id',
        'cobrador',
        'cliente',
        'nro_cuota'
    );

    $crud->columns(
        'cobrador',
        'cliente',
        'nro_cuota'
    );

    $crud->set_relation('cobrador', 'cobradores', 'apellido_nombre');
    $crud->set_relation('cliente', 'clientes', 'apellido_nombre');          

    $output = $crud->render();          

    $this->load->view('cobranzas/cobranzas_v', $output);

}catch(Exception $e){

    show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

}

and I wrote a model, I`m not sure if this is the right way, but I don't know how I must call it

```
class Compare_values_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function compare($id)
    {

    $this->db->select('"SELECT * FROM `cobranzas` WHERE `cliente` = '$cliente' AND `nro_cuota` = '$nro_cuota'"');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 

    }

}
```

Hope can help me I couldn't find some examples on internet to learn more, thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to get not matching records right?

Answer (score 0):

You said **I need to compare two values in a table: cliente and nro_cuota, if both exist I don't want to add it**. But you are matching the variables with fields. So just check `not equal` as below:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `cobranzas` WHERE `cliente` <> '$cliente' AND `nro_cuota` <> '$nro_cuota'");
```

**Note**: Remove extra single quote in your query

Comment: thanks Kumar_v! but I have no results, what I need is to find a way to make a condition before insert. In pseudo code should be something like if cliente and nrocuota exist {dont insert} else {insert}, I'm stuck since several days, and I couldnt find examples which help me.